# How to merge git forks with current ROS directories? Camera_pose errors

Tags: ros, kinect, ros-hydro, github, git

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Since camera_pose_calibration was never updated, I finally got the patched version of camera_pose from Github via this:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/jbohren-forks/camera_pose.git
```

Unfortunately I'm not allowed to modify the files in ROS directories.  I figured out that I would refer to the folder I put it in over the original ROS camera_pose folder by listing it first in ROS_PACKAGE_PATH but I'm still getting errors.  How would I eliminate the old camera_pose folder?  Using ROS Hydro right now.

Edit 1: After following the overlay instructions and using roscd to check that camera_pose is being looked at in my testspace first (it is), I'm encountering new errors.

This white text

> terminate called after throwing an
> instance of
> 'pluginlib::LibraryLoadException'
> what():  rospack could not find the
> image_transport package containing
> image_transport::PublisherPlugin

Followed by this red text

> [kinect_1/stereo_cb_detector-2]
> process has died [pid 3069, exit code
> -6, cmd /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/calibration/image_cb_detector/bin/image_cb_detector_action image:=image_throttle
> camera_info:=camera_info
> __name:=stereo_cb_detector __log:=/home/robot2/.ros/log/6b38aca2-7e0e-11e3-8b67-b8ca3a789964/kinect_1-stereo_cb_detector-2.log].

This error shows for all 3 Kinects.

Another white error

```
/home/robot2/Desktop/Testspace/src/camera_pose/camera_pose_calibration/src/camera_pose_calibration/multicam_capture_exec.py", line 43, in <module>
    from camera_pose_calibration.robot_measurement_cache import RobotMeasurementCache
ImportError: No module named camera_pose_calibration.robot_measurement_cache
```

Followed by red error

```
[capture_exec-19] process has died [pid 3315, exit code 1, cmd /home/robot2/Desktop/Testspace/src/camera_pose/camera_pose_calibration/src/camera_pose_calibration/multicam_capture_exec.py kinect_1 kinect_2 kinect_3 request_interval:=interval_filtered __name:=capture_exec __log:=/home/robot2/.ros/log/6b38aca2-7e0e-11e3-8b67-b8ca3a789964/capture_exec-19.log].
log file: /home/robot2/.ros/log/6b38aca2-7e0e-11e3-8b67-b8ca3a789964/capture_exec-19*.log
```

And a white message

```
ImportError: No module named camera_pose_calibration.msg
```

Then a bunch of angry red text.  Any ideas?  I also have included the roswtf output:

> ERROR Could not contact the following
> nodes:  * /kinect_2/stereo_cb_detector
>
> - /kinect_3/stereo_cb_detector  * /kinect_1/stereo_cb_detector
>
> ERROR The following nodes should be
> connected but aren't:  *
> /kinect_3/stereo_cb_detector->/rosout
> (/rosout)  *
> /kinect_1/stereo_cb_detector->/rosout
> (/rosout)  *
> /kinect_2/stereo_cb_detector->/rosout
> (/rosout)

And for all three:

> ERROR Errors connecting to the
> following services:  * service
> [/kinect_2/stereo_cb_detector/set_logger_level]
> appears to be malfunctioning: Unable
> to communicate with service
> [/kinect_2/stereo_cb_detector/set_logger_level]
>
> ERROR Errors connecting to the
> following services:  * service [/kinect_2/stereo_cb_detector/get_loggers]
> appears to be malfunctioning: Unable
> to communicate with service
> [/kinect_2/stereo_cb_detector/get_loggers]

Any ideas?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/117416/how-to-merge-git-forks-with-current-ros-directories?-camera_pose-errors/) by [Athoesen](https://answers.ros.org/users/8296/athoesen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 429 on 2014-01-13

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If I understand your question, I think you should clone this fork into your workspace source folder(`your_ws/src/`) and source the setup file found in `your_ws/devel/setup.bash`. This will overlay the fork package over the original package.

---

Originally posted by [gustavo.velascoh](https://answers.ros.org/users/2667/gustavo.velascoh/) with karma: 756 on 2014-01-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [felix k](https://answers.ros.org/users/606/felix-k/) on 2014-01-13**:
http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/workspace_overlaying

**Comment by [Athoesen](https://answers.ros.org/users/8296/athoesen/) on 2014-01-15**:
I found this incredibly helpful.  Unfortunately now it's producing different errors.  I'm not sure if they're from it, or just ones that were hidden by previous errors.

**Comment by [gustavo.velascoh](https://answers.ros.org/users/2667/gustavo.velascoh/) on 2014-01-15**:
Did you execute `catkin_make` on your workspace? it seems like can't find camera_pose_calibration message

**Comment by [Athoesen](https://answers.ros.org/users/8296/athoesen/) on 2014-01-15**:
Yes, I followed the directions.  It's still throwing me errors. I've tried both sourcing the workspace under my Groovy sourcing in the .bashrc file, and also just doing it from terminal window.  Each time I get TONS of errors from camera_pose_calibration, moreso than without trying to overlay.

**Comment by [simaopp](https://answers.ros.org/users/32526/simaopp/) on 2017-11-10**:
Have you solved the errors? I am getting the same errors